# HTML5 video problems on Safari

Tags: html, safari

I'm have the problem that video doesn't work in Safari, but works perfectly fine with Chrome and Firefox.

```
<video controls muted preload="none" playsinline src="/path/to/video" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Get fom VLC codec informations:

video h.264/mpeg-4 avc

audio mpeg aac audio mp4a

[image]

Comment: You realize we can't really help you with what you gave to us? Ok, so you managed to have invalid HTML in a single line, but that shouldn't be a problem. The problem lies probably in the codecs your video has been encoded with. Can you try with an other video file? For instance what when you set your url to `http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4`? Can you please try to narrow your problem enough so that we can know what we are looking for? And as always with Safari questions, I have to ask *what version are you using*?

Comment: Safari 12, thats a video https://emotionlife.ru/api/files/lessons/1545307946319.mp4

Comment: Get fom VLC codec informations: video h.264/mpeg-4 avc, audio mpeg aac audio mp4a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug* in Safari (at least 12.0.2), which doesn't accept to fetch this [300MB video](https://emotionlife.ru/api/files/lessons/1545307946319.mp4) as a single Request from the MediaElement.
They try desperately to make a Range request, but your host doesn't allow such requests. You can see it by trying to seek in the video while not fully loaded in other browsers.

You could workaround that issue by either

- Setting your server so that it accepts Range requests (that would be the best solution, even for other browsers).
- On error, fetch the whole file through AJAX and play it from memory (as a Blob). But this means waiting for the 400MB to be downloaded.
- On error, fetch the file and pipe a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) to a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource)'s [SourceBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer) using its [`appendStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/appendStream) method. But no browsers supports it yet...

<sub>*Though I found [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6) which says that "*HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range requests*", so it is for iOS, but they probably have the same constraints for desktop. But that they do not support non-range requests sounds like a bug anyway as it goes against the specs.</sub>

Comment: I have video with size 28,1MB but it not working too

Comment: @AlexandrLukovnikov same server right? Usually ranges are in the order of 2KB. And I suspect that anyway if they don't have a satisfying response at preflight they just abort (once again this is a browser bug)

Comment: Can your get a link to this bug?

Comment: No, I'm not sure it's been reported yet, but it is clearly a bug since it should work but doesn't. Ps: http://jsfiddle.net/n6usLq25/ And after a small research, [Here for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6) they say that the server **must** accept range-requests. This is against specs so still qualifies as a bug IMM, even though an accepted one.

Comment: Can I just set "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in server response?

Comment: I don't think so no ;-) If they require a server that does handle range request, it's because they need it (and not only the header). But how come your server doesn't accept range requests?

Comment: Thanks! I add range response and now its wokr (I use PlayFramework https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#Range-requests-support)

Comment: Unrelated, but how did you make the text on the bottom of your post so small?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution for you future searchers: (If your problem is not a mimetype issue.)

For some reason videos would not play on iPad unless i set the controls="true" flag.

Example: This worked for me on iPhone but not iPad.

```
<video loop autoplay width='100%' height='100%' src='//some_video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven’t solved the problem yet then go to your phone setting then choose safari and tap Clear History and Website Data, that worked for me the problem wasn’t the code but safari itself.