# Html Video Tag plays in Firefox and others but not in Safari (12.0.2)

Tags: node.js, safari, html5-video

I have a webpage that has a few small videos (< 1 MB in size) below the fold that I lazyload. It works just fine in Firefox and Chrome. But it fails in Safari.

In Safari's console I see no error messages. On the Server (node.js) end I see that the Video files were successfully transferred.

-------  HTML Code. ------

```
<video controls preload="none" width="230" poster="../assets/placeholder.jpg" class="videoCenteredInSection lazy">
    <source data-src="../assets/All-In-One.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Safari also had issues with LazyLoading using 'IntersectionObserver' so as a fallback I'm simply assigning video.src as the value from 'data-src' and I can see that it works because the request for correct video files is received by node server and the files are served to Safari.

------ node.js code ---

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fileToSend);
res.end(fileContents, 'utf-8');
```

I've tried with and without 'utf-8', made no difference. Works on other browsers, but not safari.

I see some posts that suggest I need to have range headers supported, but I don't see how that would help because the files are very small and also when I hit play on Video, I don't see any request go out to my server. Neither do I see any logs/errors in Console of the browser.

Please advice how to resolve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952944/html5-video-problems-on-safari
this link may be help you

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadYasir. I was trying to not go that route thinking that the Video files are under 1MB and there may be a way. But once I enabled range headers it started working for Safari.